# Call custom attributes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jQuery content slider that gives the current visible slide a class of `.swipeview-active`, and each slide has its own `data-page-index` number. I have some variables where I get the window height etc, but how do I set a retrieve the value for the `data-page-index` of the current active slide for use in a variable, for example:

```
var h = $(window).height(),
    w = $(window).width(),
    active = $('.swipeview-active'),
    dpi = $('active').data("date-page-index"),
```

so every time I call `dpi` it should put in the value of the active slides `data-page-index`, but that doesn't work. Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know any HTML element with tag `active`...

Comment: @FelixKling I assumed it was a typo for a class selector. The OP also called the attribute `date-page-index` in his code example too.

Comment: @Rory: Just wanted to raise awareness :)

Comment: You are referring to `data-page-index` but actually using `date-page-index`. Which one is a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing a `data-*` attribute via `data()` you don't need the `data-` prefix. Try this:

```
dpi = $('active').data("page-index")
```

You can also access a `data` attribute which was present on an element on page load via `attr()` - although it is not the preferred method. This method will require the `data` prefix.

```
dpi = $('active').attr("data-page-index")
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `pageIndex`?

Comment: @Asad no, as the attribute name is `data-page-index`. All that gets removed is the `data-` prefix.

Comment: I'm pretty sure data attributes with embedded hyphens get camel cased. [This part](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) of the documentation suggests so.

Comment: @Asad in fact, both works but better seems to use camelCase as you suggested

Comment: @Asad it seems you're correct - http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/LRus6/. Every day is a school day:)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't realise the other form worked (I've become too used to the native `element.dataset.noHyphensCamelCasedVersion` to remember that jQuery adds a bit of extra flexibility to everything). The more I know. :)

Comment: Unfortunately i am unable to see if this works. To test it I have been using an alert to give me the data-page-index but it returns as undefined when using: 'alert('' +dpi+ '');'

Comment: @TimWilkinson Another problem is that the selector `"active"` will always result in an empty collection, since HTML has no `active` elements.